# Should peanut shells be composted?

Tags: compost

I have read that one shouldn't compost nuts or peanut butter because of their high oil and fat content. I am wondering if the same thing goes for peanut shells? I have a lot of peanut shells and I hope I can compost with them rather than throw them away.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, peanut shells are a fine high-carbon addition to your compost pile. Adding peanut shells to your compost will probably tend to dry it out, so make sure you either add water or use enough high-moisture ingredients (e.g. most kitchen scraps or coffee grounds). Also, if you're lacking in high-nitrogen ingredients, then they will take longer to compost.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, peanut shells can be compostable, but be sure that there is no salt on them. Often peanut shells have been salted, and these should not be added to compost because the salt will stay in the soil and damage plants.

Comment: +1  Like most things, a salted peanut isn't going to harm it (as a few salted potato chips aren't) but don't go adding a whole bag of them!

Comment: You can of course, rinse the salt off first.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, peanut hulls compost well, but if you have quite a lot, I know from experience they work great as mulch.  I live in "Peanut Country" so peanut hulls are available here and they work great!!

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to make a compost with peanut shells. I bought 60 kgs grounded peanut shell and mix it with 500 kg cow manure and 25 kgs ammonium nitrate.I used the ammonium nitrate to make the composting process faster. I covered the mixture with plastic tent to make it hotter. I have mixed them 50 days ago and will wait almost 3 months more. I will test the the manure mixture on tomatos in two groups with peanut and witout peanut mixture. then I will compare the results on leaves color and harvest.

P.S : the inadeuqate cosposted peanut shells can cause fungus. compost the peanut as long as you can